# I would like migrate Oralce DB to Amazon Redshift with AWS SCT

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-redshift, aws-sct

## Overview

I learn to migrate an Amazon RDS for Oracle Database to Amazon Redshift referring this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_RDSOracle2Redshift.html

## Trouble

In [step5](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_RDSOracle2Redshift.Steps.ConvertSchema.html), I use Amazon SCT to convert the Oracle Schema to Amazon Redshift.
But, I have to change config for Amazon SCT because the tutorial document is old written in 2017.
One of the change config, I try to [disable to use AWS Glue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmfcz.png).
I open [Project settings to uncheck the checkbox "Use AWS Glue"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFuZs.png).
And soon after, [AWS SCT froze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUX5v.png).

My PC has 8GB memory, and I try business PC which has 16GB memory.
Still it is useless.

## What I try

According to [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/database/configuring-the-aws-schema-conversion-tool/),I need to increase JVM size. So, I edit the configuration files for SCT.

```
[Application]
app.name=AWS Schema Conversion Tool
app.version=1.0.645
app.runtime=$ROOTDIR\runtime
app.identifier=com.amazon.sct
app.classpath=$ROOTDIR\app\AWSSchemaConversionTool.jar;$ROOTDIR\app\AWSSchemaConversionToolBatch.jar
app.mainjar=$ROOTDIR\app\AWSSchemaConversionTool.jar
app.mainclass=com.amazon.sct.App

[JavaOptions]
-Xss128M
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseParallelGC
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED

[JVMUserOptions] #add
–Xmx4096m        #add 
–Xms2048m        #add

[ArgOptions]
```

I finish editing the files and restart AWS SCT, but [JVM memory does not increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IuJ2.png).

I have no idea about sovling the trouble. What should I do next?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Resolution

Once, I uninstalled AWS SCT, and I reinstalled old version one.
Then, I could open the Project settings windows and uncheck [Use AWS Glue]
[Project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Daq.png)

Answer (score 0):

No wonder it’s going wrong. You have a stack size of 128Mb per thread, but only 4096Mb overall. That gives you only enough space to use 40 threads, and then not have any objects in the heap.

Probably best to uncomment all of the space sizes and let the JVM do its thing automatically.

Comment: You say that I should remove the below code [JVMUserOptions], right?
At first, I use AWS SCT at default config. But, AWS SCT froze after I open the project setting.
So, I edit the configuration files for SCT to increase JVM memory.
Is my think right?