# AWS Redshift failed connect [Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out]

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, database-migration, aws-sct

## Overview

I learn to migrate an Amazon RDS for Oracle Database to Amazon Redshift referring this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_RDSOracle2Redshift.html

## Trouble

I had a trouble the below question.
[I would like migrate Oralce DB to Amazon Redshift with AWS SCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449294/i-would-like-migrate-oralce-db-to-amazon-redshift-with-aws-sct/65520396#65520396)

I managed to get out of trouble with the help of people. However, I had a new trouble.
I try to connect to Amazon Redshift with AWS SCT. AWS Redshift failed to connect.
[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0MIT.png)

I saw the log file. An error was recorded in the log.

```
2020-12-31 20:56:16.358 [  78]      LOADER ERROR   Connection to 'jdbc:redshift://oracletoredshiftdwusingdms-redshiftcluster-1dll5wg4tqddk.cnxpo3loreqp.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/test' wasn't established. ERROR: code: 500150; message: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect.
2020-12-31 20:56:16.358 [  78]      LOADER ERROR   Error chain:
[Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect.
------------------------------
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect.
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.JdbcDriverAdapter.connect(JdbcDriverAdapter.java:30)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderDataSource.testConnection(DbLoaderDataSource.java:109)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.SqlLoaderEngine.testConnection(SqlLoaderEngine.java:1706)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.checkConnection(DbLoader.java:706)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.connect(DbLoader.java:406)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderContainer.checkAccessibility(DbLoaderContainer.java:30)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:40)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:18)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1425)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect.
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:476)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:468)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:694)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:100)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.JdbcDriverAdapter.connect(JdbcDriverAdapter.java:30)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderDataSource.testConnection(DbLoaderDataSource.java:109)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.SqlLoaderEngine.testConnection(SqlLoaderEngine.java:1706)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.checkConnection(DbLoader.java:706)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.connect(DbLoader.java:406)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderContainer.checkAccessibility(DbLoaderContainer.java:30)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:40)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:18)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1425)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2020-12-31 20:56:16.359 [  78]     GENERAL INFO    Test connecting to Amazon Redshift database finished in 0:00:21.113 sec with memory consumption of 516.25 MB (497.79 MB .. 516.25 MB).
2020-12-31 20:56:16.359 [  78]     GENERAL INFO    Test connecting to Amazon Redshift database statistics:
    GENERAL: 0:00:21.113 sec
2020-12-31 20:56:16.365 [  19]     GENERAL ERROR   com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderHandledException: Connection wasn't established. Check connection properties.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderHandledException: Connection wasn't established. Check connection properties.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.launcher.CommonTaskLauncher.lambda$run$0(CommonTaskLauncher.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:106)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.setState(Task.java:698)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.lambda$call$2(Task.java:1455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:509)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:635)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:465)
    at javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.showAndWait(HeavyweightDialog.java:162)
    at javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:346)
    at com.amazon.sct.handler.CreateConnectionHandler.createConnection(CreateConnectionHandler.java:51)
    at com.amazon.sct.viewmodel.AppViewModel.createConnection(AppViewModel.java:1406)
    at com.amazon.sct.viewmodel.AppViewModel.createTargetConnection(AppViewModel.java:774)
    at com.amazon.sct.view.AppView.loadTarget(AppView.java:348)
    at com.amazon.sct.view.AppView.lambda$initConnectionMenusBindings$27(AppView.java:1077)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderHandledException: Connection wasn't established. Check connection properties.
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.checkConnection(DbLoader.java:721)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoader.connect(DbLoader.java:406)
    at com.amazon.sct.dbloader.DbLoaderContainer.checkAccessibility(DbLoaderContainer.java:30)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:40)
    at com.amazon.sct.task.TestConnectionTask.call(TestConnectionTask.java:18)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1425)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    ... 1 more
```

## What I try

`[Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect.`

I think the above error is similar to the [issues](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/160).
So, I launched the Security Groups console and add [Rule: Type=Redshift, Source=MyIP].

I saved it and I try to connect again.
Unfortunately, AWS Redshift failed to connect with same error.
I have no idea to do next time.
What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this issue, you can use following steps;

(1) To troubleshoot faster, instead of your java application, you can use ping command to check network reachability from your host/machine/laptop/desktop.

(2) If step one is successful, then try following commands on your host/machine/laptop/desktop using Windows command prompt or Windows PowerShell or Any Linux shell/command line tool;

nc -vz -w 3 "${DB_HOST}" "${DB_PORT}"

OR

telnet "${DB_HOST}" "${DB_PORT}"

(3) If commands from step (1) or (2) are failing with "Connection timed out" error, then

(3.1) Use [VPC Reachability Analyzer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-insights-analyzes-reachability-and-visibility-in-vpcs/) : Create and analyze path with Source type Network Interfaces and Source as Network Interface Id of the machine where you application is deployed. Furthermore, select Destination type as Network Interfaces and Destination as network Interface Id of the AWS Red Shift. Put Destination port as 5439, keep Protocol as TCP.
*Note*: It takes few minutes for completion of this path analysis.

OR

(3.2) If you have enabled VPC Flow Logs, then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which AWS resource is rejecting the network traffic. For VPC flow logs information please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) document from AWS.

Comment: In the step 2, should I try this command in CMD?

Comment: @cecilia - On the source host/machine you can use any command line interface of your choice. such as Windows PowerShell or Any Linux shell/command line tool. It depends up on type of OS/tool you have. You might need to install these commands if not present.