# Can't connect AWS Aurora Serverless database to MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I used the following command to create a Aurora serverless db:

```
 aws rds create-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier db-test --engine aurora-mysql --engine-version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1 --engine-mode serverless --scaling-configuration MinCapacity=1,MaxCapacity=2,SecondsUntilAutoPause=1000,AutoPause=true --master-username xxx --master-user-password xxx  --db-cluster-parameter-group-name xxx  --db-subnet-group-name xxx --vpc-security-group-ids xxxxx xxxxxx
```

The db cluster got created and showing me 'available', but I can't connect it to the MySQL Workbench, error message:

`Failed to Connect to MySQL at xxxx xxxx with user xxx`

When I tried in a different AWS account and it works, I assume maybe it's because of the VPC/security group? I'm new to this, does anyone know why this is happening?

The security group inbound and outbound I set to all traffic but it still not working, I don't fully understand this....Can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: you can refer [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520924/aws-redshift-failed-connect-error-setting-closing-connection-connection-timed/65521204#65521204) troubleshooting steps. you might need to change port and relevant connection details.

Comment: @MarkB Nope because I don't want it to be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this means that you have not set your inbound rules correctly. As explained in this [AWS RDS tutorial](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker), you need to ensure that your inbound rules are set up properly. When you set them, try using **My IP** for your development environment in the AWS Management Console.

[image]